# Iron-Router onBeforeAction Meteor v1.0

Tags: meteor, iron-router

before the release of Meteor v1.0, I was running this code with success:

```
onBeforeAction: function(){

 if(Meteor.userId()){

    Meteor.call('create_game', this.params._id, 1, function(error, result){
    if (error)
     console.log(error);
    else{
      var game_id = result; 
      Session.set('gamesolo_id', game_id);  
    }
   });
  }
},
waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('game', Session.get('gamesolo_id'))},
```

Since Meteor v1.0, this.next() is needed in the onBeforeAction hook. I tried this:

```
onBeforeAction: function(){

 if(Meteor.userId()){

    Meteor.call('create_game', this.params._id, 1, function(error, result){
    if (error)
     console.log(error);
    else{
      var game_id = result; 
      Session.set('gamesolo_id', game_id);  
    }
   });
   this.next();
  }
},
waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('game', Session.get('gamesolo_id'))},
```

But it turns out in a loop calling for ever the method.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe try putting `this.next()` outside of `if` statement

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But outside does not change anything. The method is called is a loop forever and the template continuously switches between the loading template and the page template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `onRun` now instead of `onBeforeAction` (and `this.next()` is not needed).

Comment: Interesting. I haven't found any hook called onRunAction in the doc. Anyway, it does not work for me cause I do not get the subscription to the game just created. I need a hook that create a game before I subscribe to it with waitOn. Basically, onBeforeAction ... but I just do not what to do with this.next()

Comment: Sorry, it's `onRun` (http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#available-hook-methods). I've updated the answer.